# Makefile, declare variable in executable

Tags: makefile

This is a simple question for a starter like me, but what can I do to do like the following

```
all: run
run:
        DIR=bin/
        $(CC) $(LIBRARY) $(INCLUDE) run.o -o $(DIR)$@
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, you have an assignment to the shell variable `DIR` on one command line.  On the next line, you have the expansion of a `make` variable `DIR`.  This doesn't work because the two lines are executed by different shells, and in any case, `make` expands `$(DIR)` before running the shell and `DIR` is not a `make` variable.

You could make it work like this:

```
all: run
run:
        DIR=bin/; \
        $(CC) $(LIBRARY) $(INCLUDE) run.o -o $${DIR}$@
```

The backslash means the two lines are treated as one (so much so that the semicolon is needed).  The `$${DIR}` notation is expanded by `make` to `${DIR}` (more precisely, `$$` expands to `$` and `make` ignores the `{DIR}`), and then the shell expands `${DIR}` from the value set previously.  You could, of course, omit the braces.

However, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17800517/15168) by [BeSerK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584162/berserk) is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Well, I actually what to use multiple independent targets on a make file. Thanks you very much, and BeSerk also.

Answer (score 1):

Why not go like this?

```
DIR=bin/
all: $(DIR)/run
$(DIR)/run:
        $(CC) $(LIBRARY) $(INCLUDE) run.o -o $@
```